# Unusual potentiometer pin configuration

Tags: identification, potentiometer, pinout

I'm trying to identify this 30 year old ø24mm 10k log potentiometer so that I can replace it.  The only marks on the rear are "RC-302" and "1348616" but that doesn't turn up anything in my searches so I'm looking for a modern equivalent.

What's the right name for this pin configuration, where the pins are reversed such that the shaft of the pot goes back through the PCB to which it's soldered?

(If I search for "reverse" I just get links pointing me to log pots with a reverse log taper).

[image: EII volume pot]

Answer (score 2):

Bourns simple calls it "Front Facing", but other manufacturers might use different terminology.

Answer (score 1):

One variation is "panel mount".
These may have pins "straight out" or bent.

[These](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tt-electronics-bi/P160KNPD-4FC20B10K/987-1314-ND/2408891)  Digikey items look like what's wanted.
TTElectronics/BI 155 in stock $0.79/1. Buy 10 now :-)

[image]

---

[Here](https://buildyourcnc.com/item/Laser-Component-Potentiometer-5k-Rotary-newbiehack-Potentiometers-Potentiometer-5K-Rotary) is a similar arrangement but, as above, with only the pins proper bent forwards.
[image]

That appears to have been copied from [here](https://www.newbiehack.com/categories/Laser-Component-Potentiometer-5k-Rotary-newbiehack-Potentiometers-Potentiometer-5K-Rotary)

Available here from [Galco](https://www.galco.com/shop/KU-Precision-Electronic-Components-Panel-Mount-Potentiometers?source=YouTubeText)

Comment: Interesting, thanks!  The pin configurations don't quite match the original 24mm pot (the pins are in a straight line) but it might be possible to make them fit.

Comment: Hmm, I might be able to make a TT P231 series fit by bending the pins back in the opposite direction...   (although those only have a 6mm shaft rather than the 6.35mm of the original)

Comment: You may also be able to use a pot with tags with holes that extend radially and wrap a stiff wire around the pins, solder it and  then extend the wire out in a forward direction. That gives good flexibility for spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Codenummer: 1348616

Made: April 1986 (week 16)

Manufacturer: CentraLab, Inc.
(Widely used by Gibson)

https://www.guitarinsite.nl/serienummers-potmeter_eng.php